# This Code is stopping halfway through

Tags: vba, excel

My below code was all running perfectly fine when I had it all in one function, now that I separated it into a different function for better readability and easier modifications, it's stopping after the function call. Does anyone know why its doing this?

```
            If (Not (Find_First("ERR", Sheets("Consolidated_Data850").Range("G:G")))) Then
                Debug.Print "No data errors found!"
                Call SaveFile(TempFilePath & "ValidPOs.xls")

'                LR = Sheets("Consolidated_Data850").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row
'                Debug.Print "Saving file to... " & Chr(13) & SaveFilePath & "\ValidPOs.xls"
'                If Dir(SaveFilePath & "\ValidPOs.xls") <> "" Then Kill SaveFilePath & "\ValidPOs.xls"
'                ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs FileName:=SaveFilePath & "\ValidPOs.xls", FileFormat:=51
'                Call GenerateEmail(TempFolder & ValidFileName, _
'                    SaveFilePath & "\ValidPOs.xls", _
'                    Sheets("Consolidated_Data850").Range("A:F" & LR))

                    "(" & MarksFolder & ValidTemplate & ") using Range(" & Range("A:F" & LR).Address & ")"
                Call GenerateEmail(MarksFolder & ValidTemplate, _
                    TempFilePath & "ValidPOs.xls", _
                    Sheets("Consolidated_Data850").Range("A:F" & LR))
            Else
                Debug.Print "Found errors"
            End If
```

New function that replaced the comment section above...

```
Private Sub SaveFile(FileNamePath As String)

    LR = Sheets("Consolidated_Data850").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row
    Debug.Print "Savingfile to... " & FileNamePath

    If Dir(FileNamePath) <> "" Then Kill FileNamePath
    On Error GoTo ErrHandler:
        Debug.Print "Generating Email (" & TempFilePath & "ValidPOs.xls" & ")" & Chr(13) & _
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs FileName:=FileNamePath, FileFormat:=51

Exit Sub

ErrHandler:
    Debug.Print "Error # " & Str(Err.Number) & " was generated " _
        & Err.Source & Chr(13) & "Error Line: " & Erl & Chr(13) & Err.Description
End Sub
```

Everything works perfectly, but once it leaves that second function (after the save) it stops and does not continue the code

**EDIT**

It seems as thought the code just stops here, and it's **NOT** calling the function

[image]

Comment: Do you have any error traps? Any errors? Have you tried stepping thru the code?

Comment: That's what all the `Debug.Print` lines are for, and no I don't have any error traps anywhere... No error messages, just stops

Comment: It just stops immediately after `Call SaveFile(TempFilePath & "ValidPOs.xls")` with no error and it does not print out the `Debug` message after that

Comment: so does this line get executed: 

Debug.Print "Generating Email (" & TempFilePath & "ValidPOs.xls" & ")" & Chr(13) & _
                    "(" & MarksFolder & ValidTemplate & ") using Range(" & Range("A:F" & LR).Address & ")"

if it doesn't, set some if statements to output each of the variables in that line since one of them must be null or something.

Comment: @chris-crush-code No it does not, that's where it stops

Comment: I would place an error trap in the subroutine AND a Debug.Print as the last executable line AND a breakpoint in the subroutine and step thru the code. I'm betting you  have an error in there..

Comment: So I added the error catcher, and it's not finding anything... I also used break points and its not even going passed the `Debug.Print "Generating Email (" & TempFilePath & "ValidPOs.xls" & ")" & Chr(13) & _ "(" & MarksFolder & ValidTemplate & ") using Range(" & Range("A:F" & LR).Address & ")" `

Comment: When I comment out the `Debug.Print` line it continues to the `Call GenerateEmail` function and then stops there again and doesn't go into that function

Comment: Actually I had wanted an error trap in your 'SaveFile' subroutine, but it seems to magically get to the Debug.Print now?  Also, you need an 'Exit Sub/Function just BEFORE your error trap, else you will fall into it and scratch your head. In the VBA windo, take a look at Tools | Options | General Tab and tell me which Error Trapping setting you have.

Comment: No the break point get to that and when I hit next it doesn't read out that Debug.Print which is weird... I've got `Break on Unhandled Errors`

Comment: Then when the breakpoint is stopping there, examine EVERY variable referenced in the Print. If you remove the line continuation (all on one line) you could try copying all but the 'Debug.Print', past into the Immediate window (precede with a '?') then press enter. That will attempt to display all. Otherwise, just copy the variable names, use the '?' one by one... or hover the cursor over the variable.

Comment: I moved the error handler to the `SaveFile` Function and it seems the error is coming from there... `Error #  0 was generated Error Line: 0`

Comment: No, that's because you didn't exit the sub like I suggested above. "Also, you need an 'Exit Sub/Function just BEFORE your error trap, else you will fall into it and scratch your head."

Comment: Sorry I'm a little newby when it comes to error handling... Maybe we should move this to discussion chat?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157677/discussion-between-wayne-g-dunn-and-maldred).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the error in the code above... The Range I was using to pass into the `GenerateEmail()` function was too broad of a range, the `LR` wasn't being set to a number and was using the entire column instead of a the Last Row that was **NOT** being calculated

Appreciate everyone for the assistance in error handling and debugging!

Answer (score 0):

Call SaveFile(TempFilePath & "ValidPOs.xls")

Are you sure that TempfilePath is a valid path and that it ends with a "\"?
If you step through with F8 does it highlight the End Sub before stopping or does the yellow highlight vanish from ActiveWorkbook.saveas without moving on?

Check the date and time last saved for your activeworkbook - is it actually being saved? My money is on some error here - out of disk space, invalid path or similar. But if not - and this is pretty random but replace the call - just use

```
 SaveFile TempFilePath & "ValidPOs.xls"
```

(Note no brackets if you omit the call) - I have had it sometimes work with the shorthand when it's failed on the formal syntax.

Edited in reponse to code changes: You need to Exit Sub before your error handler

Private Sub SaveFile(FileNamePath As String)

```
LR = Sheets("Consolidated_Data850").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row
Debug.Print "Savingfile to... " & FileNamePath

If Dir(FileNamePath) <> "" Then Kill FileNamePath
On Error GoTo ErrHandler:
    Debug.Print "Generating Email (" & TempFilePath & "ValidPOs.xls" & ")" & Chr(13) & _
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs FileName:=FileNamePath, FileFormat:=51


 EXIT SUB ' if you miss this your error handler below is run irrespective of 
 ' whether there's an error or not.


ErrHandler:
    Debug.Print "Error # " & Str(Err.Number) & " was generated " _
    & Err.Source & Chr(13) & "Error Line: " & Erl & Chr(13) & 
Err.Description
```

End Sub

Comment: I've verified `TempFilePath` is accurate and verified the `\` at the end as well. I would make it into one line, however I have to convert the FileFormat to xls before I send it out by email. I've also checked that it's saving properly and it is... double checked time and it was 2 seconds, I also see the saving progress bar when it runs that line. I will try this line, maybe it is the issue however

Comment: I updated my question to reflect the error catch that I'm getting... You're correct, I am getting the error in this function but it's not telling me what the error is with my error handler

Comment: Added the `Exit Sub` to that line and there's no error message, it seems it may be coming from the `GenerateEmail()`

Comment: Confirmed it's stopping at `Call GenerateEmail(MarksFolder & ValidTemplate, TempFilePath & "ValidPOs.xls", Sheets("Consolidated_Data850").Range("A:F" & LR))`